# TypeError when using `useLocalObservable` from MobX to work with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I'm basically following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKNls_FReXI) which points to [this repo](https://github.com/satansdeer/mobx-react/blob/master/src/NotesContext.js) to convert my app to use MobX v6. I'm using `useLocalObservable` as `useLocalStore` is deprecated in MobX v6.

The error I get is on `FrameItStore` inside of `useLocalObservable`:

```
Argument of type 'typeof FrameItStore' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Record<string, any>'.
  Type 'typeof FrameItStore' provides no match for the signature '(): Record<string, any>'.ts(2345)
```

And then the whole return statement is in red squiggly lines in VSCode.

[image: VSCode Mobx TypeScript Error]

Would love to know how to fix it?

## types.ts

```
export type Window = {
  width: number
  height: number
}

export type Point = {
  x: number
  y: number
}

export type TrafficSignal = {
  close: string
  minimize: string
  maximize: string
}

export type TrafficSignalPosition = {
  close: Point
  minimize: Point
  maximize: Point
}

export interface IFrameItStore {
  id: number
  trafficSignalColors: Array<TrafficSignal>
}
```

## FrameItStore.ts

```
import { makeObservable, observable, action, computed } from 'mobx'

import type {
  TrafficSignal,
  Point,
  Window,
  TrafficSignalPosition,
  IFrameItStore,
} from '../types'

export class FrameItStore implements IFrameItStore {
  id = 0
  trafficSignalColors = [
    {
      close: '#EF4444',
      minimize: '#FBBE25',
      maximize: '#49DE80',
    },
    {
      close: 'black',
      minimize: 'blue',
      maximize: 'orange',
    },
  ]

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      win: observable,
      box: observable,
      boxCenter: computed,
      trafficSignalPosition: computed,
      trafficSignalColors: observable,
      id: observable,
    })
  }

  win(): Window {
    return {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
    }
  }

  box(): Window {
    return {
      width: 1024,
      height: 600,
    }
  }

  get boxCenter(): Point {
    return {
      x: (this.win().width - this.box().width) / 2,
      y: (this.win().height - this.box().height) / 2,
    }
  }

  get trafficSignalPosition(): TrafficSignalPosition {
    return {
      close: { x: this.boxCenter.x + 20, y: this.boxCenter.y + 20 },
      minimize: { x: this.boxCenter.x + 2 * 20, y: this.boxCenter.y + 20 },
      maximize: { x: this.boxCenter.x + 3 * 20, y: this.boxCenter.y + 20 },
    }
  }
}

export const config = new FrameItStore()
```

## FrameItContext.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useLocalObservable } from 'mobx-react'

import { FrameItStore } from './FrameItStore'

const FrameItContext = React.createContext(null)

export const FrameItProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactChild }) => {
  const frameItStore = useLocalObservable(FrameItStore)

  return (
    <FrameItContext.Provider value={frameItStore}>
      {children}
    </FrameItContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useFrameItStore = () => React.useContext(FrameItContext)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo you are following [returns an object](https://github.com/satansdeer/mobx-react/blob/454e3ce77fca34b4496b0e478345110c02b21142/src/notesStore.js#L4-L15) that is [used for `useLocalStore`](https://github.com/satansdeer/mobx-react/blob/454e3ce77fca34b4496b0e478345110c02b21142/src/NotesContext.js#L8). An equivalent in your code would be to use an instance of your `FrameItStore` class for `useLocalObservable`.

You can also return this instance from a function given to `useLocalObservable` to only create a single instance once on the first render of the component.

```js
const FrameItContext = React.createContext<IFrameItStore | null>(null);

export const FrameItProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactChild }) => {
  const frameItStore = useLocalObservable(() => new FrameItStore());

  return (
    <FrameItContext.Provider value={frameItStore}>
      {children}
    </FrameItContext.Provider>
  );
};
```